# How to avoid the GPU draw to the ineffectively offscreen buffer each time I call an `glDrawArrays` function?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, gpu

We are using `GPU` to do image processing in `OpenGL ES` shader language, and output the result image to an offscreen render buffer. I assume the GPU will update the frame each time I call [glDrawArrays](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml). But we have more than ten array to draw, so I think there can be potential performance issue here.

So how can we avoid the `GPU` update the frame buffer after all the ten `glDrawArrays` finished.

Comment: What makes you think this is happening? How draw calls are handled is entirely implementation and architecture dependent. The OpenGL implementation can and will queue up draw calls as long as it wants, as long as they are handled before the result is needed. For example, it could work very differently between a GPU that uses tile based rendering and a GPU that does not.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. And I'm not good at understanding how the graphic works.  I assume after `glDrawArrays` called, it will take effect as soon as possible, so if I doesn't call some API to control that, the whole image will be render more than once. Isn't this ture?

Comment: OpenGL is not a scene graph. It's a drawing API. When you call `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` it will draw that, and only that, once. Whatever you did draw in previous calls is not going to be re-drawn.

Comment: Do you mean all the primitives are render separately as 2D image with depth buffer and combined to scene image at the last step?

Comment: No, they are added 'on top' of the already existing image.

Comment: But all the light and shadow need to re-caculate each time, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by most of what you have written in the question but in 99.9% the answer is: No, The GPU will not "update the frame buffer" because you have multiple calls to the `glDrawArrays`.

It is important to know that reducing the number of draw calls to reduce performance but having "more then 10" is pretty close to having only one draw call. You would need to exceed hundreds or thousands of draw calls to even start thinking about optimization by reducing the number of draw calls.

So let us try to understand what goes on and what are some of the components you seem to be mentioning here:

The frame buffer is the one to which you can attach the render buffers. So what is "updating the frame buffer"? This could be interpreted as the attachment have changed and the FBO was updated in terms of having different attachments. Or that the attached buffers were updated for which we can only say that they have been drawn to or they were cleared. So in the second we could say that the frame buffer was updated when you call `glDrawArrays` because the render buffer(s) has been drawn to. Note that a depth buffer is still a render buffer and is still being drawn to.

The `glDrawArrays` is one of the draw calls which usually takes most of the time to complete. There are few reasons for the draws to take long and they depend on the scenario. A most common primitive that is drawn is a triangle with which we then compose more complex shapes such as for instance a 3D model of a face. Such a model may consist of few thousands triangles and drawing them to a 100x100 part of the buffer (is far away) will usually result in overhead by having too many vertices. I am not saying that drawing them to 1000x1000 would reduce the time (it would increase it) but I am saying you can optimize those to use a less detailed model to draw when it is far or when it is small. But this is probably not your case since you are doing the image processing. The other scenario is when having lots of fragments (pixels) to which you draw. Drawing a rectangle which takes 1000x1000 pixels in the buffer will redraw 1000*1000 pixels. If you need to write to them there is not much to do but for instance if you have 1000x1000 buffer and draw 100 rectangles with size of 500x500 you are surely having an overhead and may again think about optimizations (they are not always possible though). The only thing that is left here is the complexity of the drawing. If using shaders then the vertex shader may be overcomplicating (which rarely happens), a fragment shader is most usually the bottleneck but I am sure you can find loads of posts about it. And then there is blending; If possible simply disable the blending. This may have a huge impact on the drawing performance.
But in any case the draw call will only draw to the render buffers that are currently attached to the bound frame buffer. There is nothing else that is done with it. Nothing else is updated.

So you are doing some image processing... You should be a bit more specific about that:

If for instance you are applying some filters to it such as blur, color swapping and such and the 10 draw calls is actually meant as redrawing the image for each filter where you apply 10 filters then the optimization is quite obvious: Use shaders and try merging the filters so the image is redrawn as least times as possible.

If you are processing in a way where you are producing extra data such as edge detection, OCR... then start thinking about reducing the size of the image, redraw it to a smaller buffer and do the magic there then use this buffer as a texture then apply it to the original image.

Also when you keep redrawing the same image by using multiple FBOs with attached texture you can check a bit about texture parameters. If the size of the source texture and the destination buffer are the same you can set the parameters to use the nearest texel instead of having a linear or trilinear interpolation setting on texture.

Comment: We are using the GPU to do filter an background image and alpha composition with 10+ small image, which may need same rotate and scale the small image before mix. So should we draw the bottom background image before the top one? And when draw top small picture, only part of the render buffer will update or every pixel of the render buffer updated? I want to understand more about the how the GPU combine all the primitive render result and get the full image.

Comment: If you draw the background image and apply the 10 small images on top then for each of the 10 small images only the part where the images are drawn will be updated, nothing else. You should draw the background image first, if you did not then you would need the depth buffer which I hope you are not using since it is incompatible with alpha blending, you need to create that manually (or maybe it would work by simply using color mask set to (true, true, true, false) which disables the drawing to the alpha channel).

Comment: For the depth buffer, will all the primitive have separate depth buffer？

Comment: No, depth buffer is just like a color buffer, it is a render buffer of the same dimensions as the color buffer which only holds a depth component. As implied in the response if depth buffer is used when drawing you also draw to the depth buffer, then the same number of pixels in the depth buffer will be updated on a draw call as on the color buffer. Think of it as if you had another color buffer which would draw grayscale where black means very far and white means very close, the fragment (pixel) Z value is used to check the value in the buffer and choose if it needs to be drawn if(Z>depth[i])

Comment: so with the depth buffer，the primtivies can be draw one by one increamentally. so how about light and shodow，if I add an primitive by  call, will all the light in other element primitive been recalculate?  And any good web material or book to understand this.

Comment: No. If possible do draw them without the depth buffer. And since you are using blending then the depth buffer is pretty much the worst way of doing it. As for the shadows it depends on the drawing. If an image of 100x100 drops a 10px glow around it then the drawing increases to 120x120 at least. But if you have a bad system of drawing shadows then it is possible that the whole screen will be updated. But to help you identify that we would need a lot more info on what you are doing and what you are using. Shadow are not a part of the openGL API directly.

Comment: Ok，I think I understand most of your comments. Any link or book for recommendation.

Comment: I find most good resources on stack overflow. As for the books they get deprecated pretty quickly but you could search around for something that is specific to the tools, platforms you are using.